# Rotation axis on different points

Tags: rigging, origin

I am making a character where the head is connected to the rest of its body using pipe work. I am having trouble with getting the rotations axis correct. I want to have the y,x and z rotational origin points be different according to the correct place of the pipe.

Could anyone provide some tips on how to go about this. I want to be able to rotate the head and get the pipes to rotate accordingly.

Thank you in andvance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using parenting with empties. The good thing about parenting is that the transforms of the parent empty will be inherited by the child, meaning the rotational origins should correct themselves. This also works when rigging

Comment: Smart! I used three empties on the different joints. These then copy the rotation of a main controller empty in only one axis. By parenting the empties to each other and parenting the joints to the empties, it now works perfectly. Thank you!